# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: JAVA_VENDOR

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, maven, amazon-s3

When I try to create bucket at aws s3, get this error: 
**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: JAVA_VENDOR
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.util.UserAgentUtils.userAgent(UserAgentUtils.java:87)
    at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.util.UserAgentUtils.initializeUserAgent(UserAgentUtils.java:73).**

I have openjdk 11; results of **java -version** command

```
openjdk version "11.0.1" 2018-10-16
OpenJDK Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.1+13, mixed mode)
```

Result of **mvn -version** command: ...**Apache Maven 3.5.4**...

This is my pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>c</groupId>
    <artifactId>e</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.19</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>regions</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.19</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-nop -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
                <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Simple create bucket example from aws:

```
import software.amazon.awssdk.regions.Region;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.S3Client;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CreateBucketConfiguration;
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.CreateBucketRequest;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("JAVA_VENDOR","Oracle Corporation");

        Region region = Region.US_WEST_2;
        S3Client s3 = S3Client.builder().region(region).build();
        String bucket = "bucket" + System.currentTimeMillis();
        CreateBucketRequest createBucketRequest = CreateBucketRequest
                .builder()
                .bucket(bucket)
                .createBucketConfiguration(CreateBucketConfiguration.builder()
                        .locationConstraint(region.id())
                        .build())
                .build();
        s3.createBucket(createBucketRequest);
    }
}
```

I made some efforts to win it:
1) try this :  `System.setProperty("JAVA_VENDOR","Oracle Corporation");`,
because the real system property has nave "java.vendor"
2) I found problem place in at software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.util.UserAgentUtils.userAgent: it calls JAVA_VENDOR from software.amazon.awssdk.utils.JavaSystemSettings

```
.replace("{java.vendor}", sanitizeInput(JavaSystemSetting.JAVA_VENDOR.getStringValue().orElse(null)))
```

But there is no field with such name in the JavaSystemSettings class. 
How can i handle it?

**TR; DR** UPDATE!
It work for me with next maven pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>c</groupId>
<artifactId>e</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>sdk-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/s3 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>s3</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.19</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/software.amazon.awssdk/regions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
        <artifactId>regions</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.19</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>bom</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.19</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `NoSuchFieldError` is caused by a version mismatch when loading a class.

(Setting properties won't fix this.  The exception refers to a field of a class, not a property in a `Properties` object.)

> But there is no field with such name in the `JavaSystemSettings` class.

Exactly!  You have a version mismatch between JARs containing the `UserAgentUtils` class and the `JavaSystemSettings` class.

Comment: You are qute right! The reason was the differ version in  <groupId>software.amazon.awssdk</groupId>
            <artifactId>bom</artifactId> and the added from maven dependencies.